# Using a separate table for custom user info w/ rails 3 and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Greeting,

I've been working on getting my devise sign up form customized for my application, and it's been a bit of a pain trying to sort out how Devise is handling things. My form is customized, but my the attributes in my new fields are not being saved to the database. I looked at something like this solution:http://blog.12spokes.com/web-design-development/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4/ (yeah it's for rails 4) but.... it doesn't feel like the cleanest way to do this. I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this now. Would you recommend moving additional user information that is unrelated to Devise authentication into a new table? If so, can I put fields for some nested elements in the Devise sign-up form without having to go through all of business in the solution above. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about trying to use the `devise_parameter_sanitizer` :

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  private
    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:additional_field1, :additional_field2, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    end
end
```

and then on your `User` model, you could simply add validation :

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :additional_field1, presence: true
  validates :additional_field2, uniqueness: true
end
```